# how do I set my html form data as variables to write to a file in VBScript?

Tags: html, variables, vbscript, writetofile

I have a Form created in Html and a VBScript to write a file to a Pickup folder for email to a certain address. I want to replace or add to the current fields in the write script with the form data as variables. What VBscript would I use to implement this?
I also want the script to be called by a submit button how would I do this?

here is my Form HTML:

```
<!doctype=html>
<html>
</div>
    <body onload="window.resizeTo(750,800)">
      <div align="left">
<font face="calibri" size="4">
<p><b>Thank you!!</b> …For taking the time to offer your subjects to the senior management via this Stakeholder forum. Please fill out the required information on the front sheet below. Use as many additional sheets as necessary.</p>
<form>
<p>
<fieldset>
<font color="0000FF">1)</font > Date of your submission <font color="grey" size="3">(__/__/20__)</font>:<br> <input type="date" STYLE= "background-color: #FFFF00" name="__/__/20__"><br>
</fieldset>
</p>
<p>
<fieldset>
<font color="0000FF">2)</font> Give Your submission a name: <font color="grey" size="3"> (This can be any inoffensive word or phrase at all… even if it doesn’t relate to the nature of the subject) </font><br>
<input type="text" STYLE= "background-color: #FFFF00" name="Submission Name">
</fieldset>
</p>
<p> 
<fieldset>
<font color="0000FF">3)</font> This Submission includes:<br>
<select>
   <option value="Select..."STYLE= "background-color: #FFFF00">Select...</option>
   <option value="Polite and detailed rant (no proposed solution(s) )" STYLE= "background-color: #FFFF00">Polite and detailed rant (no proposed solution(s) )</option>
   <option value="Problem(s) / area(s) for improvement with proposed solution(s)" STYLE= "background-color: #FFFF00">Problem(s) / area(s) for improvement with proposed solution(s)</option>
   <option value="New Idea(s) / Resurrected old idea(s)" STYLE= "background-color: #FFFF00">New Idea(s) / Resurrected old idea(s)</option>
   <option value="Abstract / Other" STYLE= "background-color: #FFFF00">Abstract / Other</option>
 </select> 
</fieldset>
</p>
<p>
<fieldset>
<font color="0000FF">4)</font> Indicate which areas of our business this submission is connected with… <font color="grey" size="3"> (delete as applicable) </font><br>
<select>
   <option value="Select..."STYLE= "background-color: #FFFF00">Select...</option>
   <option value="Customer / Supplier Aspects"STYLE= "background-color: #FFFF00">Customer / Supplier Aspects</option>
   <option value="Financial Performance" STYLE= "background-color: #FFFF00">Financial Performance</option>
   <option value="Innovation and growth" STYLE= "background-color: #FFFF00">Innovation and growth</option>
   <option value="Internal Business/Systems" STYLE= "background-color: #FFFF00">Internal Business/Systems</option>
 </select> 
</fieldset>
</p>
<p>
<fieldset>
<font color="0000FF">5)</font> Personal Details:<font color="grey" size="3"> (optional) </font><br>
First name: <input type="text" STYLE= "background-color: #FFFF00" name="firstname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" STYLE= "background-color: #FFFF00" name="lastname"><br>
   Contact Number: <input type="text" STYLE= "background-color: #FFFF00" name="contactnumber">
</fieldset>
</p>
<p>
<fieldset>
<font color="#0000ff">6)</font> The details of your submission… remembering to avoid:<br>
<ul>
 <li>Cases that are associated with just one single individual. These type of subjects are best dealt with outside of this forum</li>
 <li>Vulgarities and or insults.</li>
 </ul> 
<textarea rows="10" cols="50" col width= "100" STYLE= "background-color: #FFFF00">Dear senior management...
</textarea>
```

and here is my VBscript for writing to a file:

```
Set objFSO=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

' How to write file
outFile="\\location\file.txt"
Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(outFile,True)
objFile.Write "to:email1@mail.com" & vbCrLf
objFile.Write "from:email2@mail.com" & vbCrLf
objFile.Write "subject:This is a test." & vbCrLf
objFile.Write ("") & vbCrLf
objFile.Write "This is the body of the email." & vbCrLf
objFile.Close
```

Comment: How exactly does the form relate to the file you want to write?

Comment: The form is what I want to write to a file I want it to be written to a text file in a pickup folder to be automatically emailed through there to an email client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no simple way for creating multiline strings in VBScript. You have to use string concatenation for this:

```
form = "<!doctype=html>" & vbNewLine _
  & "<html>" & vbNewLine _
  & "</div>" & vbNewLine _
  & "    <body onload=""window.resizeTo(750,800)"">" & vbNewLine _
  & "      <div align=""left"">" & vbNewLine _
  & "<font face=""calibri"" size=""4"">" & vbNewLine _
  ...
```

Double quotes inside the strings must be escaped by doubling them (see above). However, this kind of escaping is quite error-prone in my experience. Since HTML allows single quotes around attribute values, using those would be a better option:

```
form = "<!doctype=html>" & vbNewLine _
  & "<html>" & vbNewLine _
  & "</div>" & vbNewLine _
  & "    <body onload='window.resizeTo(750,800)'>" & vbNewLine _
  & "      <div align='left'>" & vbNewLine _
  & "<font face='calibri' size='4'>" & vbNewLine _
  ...
```

Or you could read the form HTML code from a template file:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
form = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\path\to\form.txt").ReadAll
```

With that you can write the form to your output file like this:

```
objFile.WriteLine form
```

---

Side note: instead of using `.Write "..." & vbCrLf` you could simply use `.WriteLine "..."`.

Comment: So with this am I editing my HTML code to look like yours in the second script or am I adding my html code again in said format?

Comment: What do you mean by "add again"? If you want to write HTML code to a file use one of the 3 suggested methods and write the variable to a file.

Comment: I mean I want it to be submitted via a button so to do this will I need to program a button to call the script? would I need to copy my html code in the variable vbscript format underneath: Set objFSO=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Comment: Perhaps. You didn't provide enough context for a definite answer.

Comment: well what I need is I have a form that I want to be filled out by a user and when they click a button I want the form to be sent to a folder as a text file to then be emailed externally through said folder (the folder is programmed to be read by a server side program and emailed to an address)

Comment: Your button can trigger a function that retrieves the form's HTML via DOM and saves it to a file if the code is supposed to run on the client side. Or you could store the form in a variable and use the variable for page creation and sending if the code is supposed to run on the server side. However, it's pointless overhead to send the entire form instead of just the values.

Comment: Im working server side so storing the form in a variable is the best corse of action thanks :) and I agree with you about sending the whole form so would your code submit the whole form as a variable?

Comment: My code doesn't submit anything. It merely assigns a string to a variable and writes that variable to a file.

Comment: that's kinda what I meant sorry I don't have much (if no) experience with VBscript especially linking vbscript with html